# Behavior Tree loses references to Blackboard variables on editor restart (UE 5.1)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, unreal-engine5, blackboard, behavior-tree

Quick qestion if any of you encountered something similliar in UE 5.1. I'm having an issue with BehaviorTree loosing it blackboard references every time I  restart editor. It happends just in some particular cases ( seems like other services are working fine) it is a little bit annoying to setup them on each editor restart. Any idea why editor is removing them and how to prevent such behavior? Service is my custom  BP service with Base Service as parent
[image]

[image]

simple setup of variables couses BT to work proparly till the shut down of UE5, and problem reapear again on editor start.